# Understanding insulation resistance in a transformer

Tags: transformer, insulation

I looked for a schematic that shows the insulation resistances in a transformer.
I could not find any, so I drew what I think is right:

[image]

I read that there's insulation between the primary and secondary windings, between the primary windings and ground, and between the secondary windings and ground.

Is my schematic correct? (the next step is to understand how exactly insulation tests work.)

Comment: There is isolation between primary and secondary, but modeling it as a resistor is not ideal. You will probably see extremely high resistance between primary and secondary until isolation breakdown. Have you considered modeling it as a capacitor and two anti-parallel Zener diodes instead? Or just skipping it in the model and say it's not important as long as you stay within the voltage rating of the transformer?

Comment: @winny Shoukdn't that be two series zener diodes with opposite polarity?  Two parallel zeners will have the same voltage drop as a normal diode.

Comment: @SimonB Indeed. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The insulation materials used in transformers are generally so nearly perfect that their conduction of current can be taken to be zero, up to some very high breakdown voltage, after which the transformer becomes useless.

If you **do** have a transformer where significant current can flow through what should be an insulator, perhaps unwaxed paper in a humid atmosphere, or bare windings immersed in salt water, then the resistances that you need to model depend on the physical configuration of the transformer. Are both windings wound on the core, or is one wound on top of the other? The three resistors you have shown there, between both windings and the core, should be able to cover most cases.

Surface contamination with dust or moisture-attracting salts will cause a problem to transformers that use otherwise good insulation within. If this is found to be a problem in your particular environment (on a boat perhaps?) then sealing the transformer or the entire equipment it's used in will help.

Comment: Neil_IK is correct. While the insulation resistance is a test to check the condition of the insulation, it's not typical the need to model it in a circuit.